# How do I select from an array if the next element is not one plus the current element?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to select all elements from my array such that the element immediately after it is not one plus the current element.

I tried this:

```
data_col = ["46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52"]
data_col.select.with_index{|string, index| data_col[index+1] && string.to_i != data_col[index+1].to_i + 1 }
# => ["46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51"]
```

Every element is selected even though I would expect none of them (except the last one) gets selected.  How can I modify my statement to get what I want?

Comment: At least tidy up your code a little? Nobody needs to see your irb-prompts or the return value of `data_col`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
data_col.select.with_index { |number_string, index| data_col[index + 1].to_i != 1 + number_string.to_i  }
```

Or, if don't mind that you have the result elements as integer,

```
n_col = data_col.map(&:to_i)
n_col.select.with_index{ |n, i| n_col[i + 1] != n + 1 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(numbers + [nil]).each_cons(2).reject { |x, y| x.next == y }.map(&:first)
```

---

Add a `nil` at the end. We will use that to always include the last element:

```
[1, 2, 3] + [nil] # => [1, 2, 3, nil]
```

Pair each two consecutive elements:

```
[1, 2, 3].each_cons(2).to_a # => [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Remove the pairs that don't meet your criteria:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, nil].each_cons(2).reject { |x, y| x.next == y }
  # => [[2, 5], [6, nil]]
```

Get the numbers out of the pairs:

```
[[2, 5], [6, nil]].map(&:first) # => [2, 6]
```

Comment: OP is using strings

Comment: @sagarpandya82 doesn't matter, works with strings as well.

Comment: Apologies, I stand corrected. Didn't realise `String#next` works like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to use [Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

```
arr = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9]

arr.each_cons(2).
    each_with_object([]) { |(x,y),a| a << x unless x.next==y } << arr[-1]
  #=> [1, 4, 7, 9]
```

Another option is to step through an enumerator using [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek).

```
enum = arr.to_enum
a = []
loop do
  x = enum.next
  a << x unless x.succ == enum.peek
end
a << arr[-1]
  #=> [1, 4, 7, 9]
```

When the enumerator is at its end, [Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) generates a `StopIteration` exception which is handled by [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
data_col = ["46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52"]

def method(arg)
 results = []
 i = 0
  while i < arg.length
   current_num = arg[i].to_i
   next_num = arg[i + 1].to_i
   next_num - current_num != 1 ? results << current_num : nil
  i += 1
end
return results
end

p method(data_col) #[52]
```

This will also return just `[52]` like you were looking for, it uses a simple `while` loop, and is pretty easy to understand what's going on.